# db.json file is created and added to .gitignore using hexo.io

Tags: json, hexo

I have been trying to find what a `db.json` is and why it is being automatically genereated. All the documentation says in hexo.io is:

```
$ hexo clean

Cleans the cache file (db.json) and generated files (public).
```

What is this exactly? Since these are all static pages, is this some sort of makeshift database?

Answer (score 5):

most commonly `db.json` is used when you're running a server using `hexo server`. I believe its for performance improvements. It doesn't affect the generation (`hexo generate`) and deployments(`hexo deploy`)

Answer (score 2):

`db.json` file stores all the data needed to generate your site. There are all posts post, tags, categories etc. The data is stored in a JSON formatted string so it's easier and faster to parse the data and generate the site.